# Solr debugging infos - telling me nothing?

Tags: magento, debugging, solr

I'm a little bit confused. I worked some time now with solr, but i never experienced something like this:

**If i search for "reinigungsprodukte", i get "Opus 3 Leuchte" as a top result. And the explain-part does not tell me, why.**

Here are my search-params:

```
<str name="debugQuery">true</str>
<str name="fl">
id,sku,name,category_name,immer_vorne,immer_vorne_t,status,store_id,score
</str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="q">(*"reinigungsprodukte"*) OR ("reinigungsprodukte")</str>
<str name="hl.simple.pre"><em></str>
<str name="hl.simple.post"></em></str>
<str name="hl.fl">sku,name,category_name,keywords</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="hl">true</str>
<str name="fq">
(visibility:(3 OR 4)) AND (status:1) AND (store_id:1)
</str>
```

That means, i like to list all Docs, that contain "reinigungsprodukte" in any field.

The first result is ok. But where does the second one come from?

```
<result name="response" numFound="3351" start="0" maxScore="2.53099786E10">   
    <doc>
    <int name="store_id">1</int>
    <str name="sku">2200</str>
    <int name="status">1</int>
    <str name="immer_vorne_t">1</str>
    <str name="name">Neue aka Reinigungsprodukte</str>
    <str name="id">15318_1</str>
    <str name="category_name">Reinigungsmittel, Trockenreinigungssysteme</str>
    <float name="score">2.53099786E10</float>
    </doc>

    <doc>
    <int name="store_id">1</int>
    <str name="sku">5560004</str>
    <int name="status">1</int>
    <str name="name">Ersatzlampe für OPUS 3/36 Watt, 5400° Kelvin</str>
    <str name="immer_vorne_t">0</str>
    <str name="id">445_1</str>
    <str name="category_name">Leuchten, Opus</str>
    <float name="score">0.04896037</float>
</doc>
```

Here's the debugging-part of the response:

```
<lst name="explain">
    <str name="15318_1">
2.53099786E10 = (MATCH) sum of:
  1.26549893E10 = (MATCH) sum of:
    0.07344055 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
      0.07344055 = queryNorm
    1.26549893E10 = (MATCH) weight(text:reinigungsprodukte in 5284) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
      1.26549893E10 = score(doc=5284,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
        0.70328265 = queryWeight, product of:
          9.576217 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=10608)
          0.07344055 = queryNorm
        1.79941724E10 = fieldWeight in 5284, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = termFreq=1.0
          9.576217 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=10608)
          1.87904819E9 = fieldNorm(doc=5284)
    0.07344055 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
      0.07344055 = queryNorm
  1.26549893E10 = (MATCH) weight(text:reinigungsprodukte in 5284) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    1.26549893E10 = score(doc=5284,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0
), product of:
      0.70328265 = queryWeight, product of:
        9.576217 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=10608)
        0.07344055 = queryNorm
      1.79941724E10 = fieldWeight in 5284, product of:
        1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
          1.0 = termFreq=1.0
        9.576217 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=10608)
        1.87904819E9 = fieldNorm(doc=5284)
</str>
    <str name="445_1">
0.04896037 = (MATCH) product of:
  0.09792074 = (MATCH) sum of:
    0.09792074 = (MATCH) product of:
      0.1468811 = (MATCH) sum of:
        0.07344055 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
          0.07344055 = queryNorm
        0.07344055 = (MATCH) MatchAllDocsQuery, product of:
          0.07344055 = queryNorm
      0.6666667 = coord(2/3)
  0.5 = coord(1/2)
</str>
```

If you look at the doc with the id 445_1 there seems to be no matching with any input-date. I seems to just output it, because it is there.

I attached the xml-output of this query, if you want to take a look. 
If you need more infos, please tell me. I will provide what is needed, to solve this strange issue.

ps: The index was updated using a magento-shop with customized solrgento module.

Comment: Hm, it seems to be because of this query: \*"searchword"\*

If i change it to: \*searchword\*  it works. But why is that?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser)

Comment: The query syntax you're using seems odd, and I'm not sure what the asterisks outside of the quotation marks are meant to do `*"reinigungsprodukte"*`, but maybe the asterisks should be inside the quotes (`"*reinigungsprodukte*"`). I notice that in your explain output references [`MatchAllDocsQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html), which makes me suspect that this odd syntax is being taken as equivalent to the standard query to match all docs, `*:*`.

Comment: If this is the problem, then the second argument may just be serving to boost the score of the correct match, so that while all documents match the main query, the _correct_ match comes first.

Comment: I already tried to change \*"reinigungsprodukte"\* to "\*reinigungsprodukte\*", but this results in an error. The quotation marks are needed, because otherwise search for TRUE-LIGHT results in nothing because of the -

But i found out that "TRUE-LIGHT" can be found and die minus is not interpreted as "not: light"